# What's a better way to calculate score based on attempts and time taken?

Tags: python, function

I have created a number guessing game, where a user chooses a range of numbers to guess from, and when the user inputs a number, the program will respond if they are too high or too low, until the user guesses correctly. The program currently takes the number of attempts, and the time taken into account. There are also different difficulties (the higher the difficulty the more numbers to guess from). I have tried to create a scoring system but I need a little more help with the math side. Right now I have this code that generates a score:

```
def scorer(tries, total_time, difficulty):
    # Tells the user how much time and how many attempts were made
    print "\nCorrect! It took you " + str(round(total_time, 2)) + \
          " seconds and " + str(tries) + " tries to guess.\n"

    # Calculates score, making lower times and fewer
    # tries yield a higher score
    # Difmod takes into account the difficulty
    # Multiply by 1000 to make number more readable
    score = 1 / (1 + (tries * round(total_time, 2))) * 1000 * dif_mod(difficulty)[1]

    # Prints the score, rounded to 1 decimal place
    print "Score: " + str(round(score, 2))
```

`tries` and `total_time` are self-explanatory, and `dif_mod` is a value I made to try to make the score 'fairer' to higher difficulties. The value of `dif_mod` is higher, the higher difficulty there is. As shown here:

```
def dif_mod(difficulty):
    if difficulty == 1:
        return [10, 1]

    elif difficulty == 2:
        return [50, 1.5]

    elif difficulty == 3:
        return [100, 2]

    elif difficulty == 4:
        return [1000, 10]

    elif difficulty == 5:
        return [10000, 20]

    elif difficulty == 0:
        return [1, 1]
```

The first value in the list is the highest possible number to guess from, the second item in the list is `dif_mod`. These are all placeholder values and I want to figure out what I should use for them.

My main aim is to make a score higher based on fewer attempts and less time taken, but to also reward a user with a higher score if they are on a higher difficulty.

Comment: But I have provided working code:   `score = 1 / (1 + (tries * round(total_time, 2))) * 1000 * dif_mod`

Comment: I just want to know if there is a better way to calculate it, and a better way to take dif_mod into account.

Comment: Everything runs fine without syntax errors when I run the whole program, for the sake of simplicity I simply posted only the code related to scoring so I didn't have ~250 lines of code for people to sift through. The edits you made do make sense though in this context.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the second piece of code was supposed to be the dif_mod function. I do see your wording now saying dif_mod comes from the second value returned in the list. Please ignore my edits, I misread.

Comment: As an aside, ```dif_mod``` could be a dictionary instead of a function - ```{1:[10,1], 2:[50, 1.5], .....}```.

Comment: Why is your calculation insufficient?  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: It would be better if you asked this at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) - which is a site for people looking for optimizations on existing, running code. StackOverflow is for when you have problems (bugs) that you need help solving. In your case though, everything is working fine you just need optimization help.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid except OP isn't looking for optimizations on existing running code, they're asking for help implementing a new feature.. which is outside the scope of Code Review.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I was referring to this _"I just want to know if there is a better way to calculate it, and a better way to take dif_mod into account."_; not sure what is the new feature here. Perhaps you can suggest an edit to make the question more about the new feature?

Comment: The code now runs as is, there are technically no bugs because it runs fine. I am indeed just looking for how to optimize the code, and want to find a better formula to calculate score. Maybe this is more suited to Code Review. Thanks.